# Setting default scatter plot marker in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to set the default marker for `plt.scatter()` - I've tried setting this line in my matplotlibrc file:

```
lines.marker    : +
```

but this doesn't appear to change the default marker, which is a circle.

http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html doesn't seem to have any other obvious parameter to set either; does anyone know if it is actually possible to set the default marker for a scatter plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing directly the code in `site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py`:

```
# This function was autogenerated by boilerplate.py.  Do not edit as
# changes will be lost
@_autogen_docstring(Axes.scatter)
def scatter(x, y, s=20, c=None, marker='+', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None,
            vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, edgecolors=None,
            hold=None, data=None, **kwargs):
    ax = gca()
    # allow callers to override the hold state by passing hold=True|False
    washold = ax.ishold()
```

**Mind the warning in the comment since I'm not sure when boilerplate.py is being called.** (You just need to try it out and see) However before actually changing the source consider overlapping `plt.scatter` with your own call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class scatter():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.marker = '+'
        plt.scatter(x,y,marker=self.marker)

x,y = np.random.randint(0,100,30),np.random.randint(0,100,30)
scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That seems to work fine, but I don't think I should be directly changing the matplotlib code! I've raised an issue here if anyone is interested: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6272

Comment: @David Stansby I agree, thus my suggestion for "overlapping" the scatter function. From the source code I don't think you have any other way of achieve that, the default parameter there for marker is pretty straightforward (thought there might be some procedures in Python I'm overlooking).